# Why can't get redirect url with curl for the specified url?

Tags: curl, redirect

Open the url `http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html` in your browser and wait for 5 seconds or so,the url will redirect into `http://quotes.money.163.com/stock`.
In some tutorial on curl command, the `L` directive tells cURL to follow redirects, the `s` directive tells cURL to be silent,the `url_effective` variable is what we're after.

```
target="http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html"
curl -Ls -w %{url_effective} -o /dev/null $target
```

Why the command above can't get the last redirected url `http://quotes.money.163.com/stock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it's a [HTML meta tag redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta), and curl does not support automatically following HTML meta tag redirects. to follow that you'll need something that understands HTML, curl does not.

`quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html` contains the html tag `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/">` which tells the browser `after 5 seconds, redirect to the root of this domain` which is `quotes.money.163.com/`, and `quotes.money.163.com/` in turn loads javascript from `http://img1.cache.netease.com/f2e/finance/backend_project/quotes_index_2014/app/dist/js/quotes_hub.916069.min.js` which contains

```
! function(o) {
    var l = location.href,
        t = !!location.hash.split("#")[1] ? location.hash.split("#")[1] : "HS",
        c = location.host,
        n = location.protocol,
        i = {
            HS: "stock",
            US: "usstock",
            HK: "hkstock",
            BOND: "bond",
            FX: "old/#FX",
            FN: "old/#FN",
            FU: "old/#FU",
            GB: "old/#GB",
            DC: "old/#DC"
        },
        e = i[t],
        a = n + "//" + c + "/stock";

    function s() {
        return l.indexOf("quotes.money.163.com/old/") > -1 ? 1 : 0
    }

    function r(o) {
        return o.indexOf("query") > -1 ? 1 : 0
    }
    if (!s()) {
        if (e) {
            location.replace(n + "//" + c + "/" + e)
        } else {
            if (r(t)) {
                location.replace(n + "//" + c + "/old/#" + t)
            } else {
                location.replace(a)
            }
        }
    }
}(this);
```

which via modifying window.location does a javascript redirect to `http://quotes.money.163.com/stock`, and to make matters worse, curl understands neither javascript redirects nor html redirects. if you want something that understands both of those, consider using a headless browser.

Comment: It seems that headless browser is the option nowadays. :( This link can help [google chrome headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#repl)